# Still missing something with Android Licensing

Tags: android, android-studio

I think I'm getting closer to my android app licensing journey but believe I am missing a key piece here.  I am using what is likely a very simple check for licensing using the code shown below.

```
if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }

            if (policyReason == Policy.LICENSED){

                // Handle licensed  
            }

            if (policyReason == Policy.NOT_LICENSED){

                // Handle not licensed
            }

            if (policyReason == Policy.RETRY){

                // handle retry
            }
```

I can use the test section on the developer web site with my test account and it works exactly how I'd like provided I select the first 4 options.

- Respond Normal
- Not Licensed
- Licensed
- Old Licensed

If I Select one of the errors, it does hit the method in my MainActivity, but at the same time, lauches right in to my app.

```
public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // This is a polite way of saying the developer made a mistake
            // while setting up or calling the license checker library.
            // Please examine the error code and fix the error.
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(errorCode), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //appLicenseError = errorCode;
        }
```

My assumption here is that this would have occurred in conjunction with the POLICY.NOT_LICENSED but clearly I am missing something.

I have the doCheck() in my MainActivity onCreate method so that is the first thing that is occurring.  It looks like the only time the following two callback events occur is when one of the first 4 licensing options are returned, not the error codes.

public void allow(int policyReason) {...

public void dontAllow(int policyReason) {

I guess my understanding after reading the documentation was that if an error occurred, such as error 3 "not market managed" that this would follow the path of non licensed and prevent my app from fully launching.  However, it seems that this results in just the error callback occurring and then it returns to my onCreate and simply launches the app.

Any pointers on how I can better handle this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this link and thought I would pass it along.  I've ran in to several sever hurdles trying to work through the licensing documentation and examples, no doubt due to my lack of knowledge, not the information.  If there are others out there still in the learning phases where Android and Java are concerned, this may help in providing a very clear and concise example of how to setup licensing and test it.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/about-app-licensing.html

The only issues I had with this example was how the author did the text views and Intent for getting and receiving the information from the main activity.  Instead of doing them in a single line (which didn't work for me), I created the references in my class and then used them in my onCreate.

This helped me a lot so I thought I'd pass it on.